# Convert image from sitecore field to base64 string

Tags: image, base64, sitecore, converters, sitecore6

I need some help with an issue if anyone could help me. I am trying get an image from a Sitecore field and convert it afterwards to a `base64` string.

What i have done is getting that content into an `ImageField` datatype, but i can't seem to find a solution to convert it to `base64`.

```cs
Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField img = itm.Fields["image"];
```

Is anyone able to help me?

Best regards,
Ionut.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to get the media item linked from the image field and create the base64 string from the media item file stream:

```cs
ImageField imageField = itm.Fields["Image"];
MediaItem mediaItem = imageField.MediaItem;
Stream stream = mediaItem.GetMediaStream();
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
img64.Src = "data:" + mediaItem.MimeType + ";base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Comment: Hey there. Back again with another question regarding this. Does anyone know how i could get the image from sitecore, but by a dimension of 440x80? I don't want to change it in sitecore, just reading it at that specific size.

Comment: I have another question regarding this issue.

How can i convert all the images that come through, into PNGs or JPEGs? I currently get GIF images too, which are not good for me.